# What does -n flags stands for after echo?

Tags: shell-script

I have the following code snippet:

```
#!/bin/sh 

if [ $1 = hi ]; then 
    echo 'The first argument was "hi"'
else
    echo -n 'The first argument was not "hi" -- ' 
    echo It was '"'$1'"'
fi
```

And I don't know what the flag -n after echo in the else statement stands for, 
does anyone knows the answer?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Try looking at the man page for echo. It's a fairly straight forward flag

Comment: @hakskel ... depending on the shell `echo` might be a built-in (e.g. in Bash, Zsh). So while there may be a `man`-page for `/bin/echo` or so, `help echo` would be the way to go in that case (i.e. Bash only). And `type echo` can be used to find out which one your shell uses (built-in or command etc ..., i.e. in both Bash and Zsh again).

Comment: http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/echo.1.html

Comment: Welcome on U&L! You'll find various relevant details in [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/315749).

Comment: Another option is to experiment and see if you observe any difference.  Try (1) `echo hi` and (2) `echo -n hi`.  Does `echo -n` behave differently?

Answer (score 4):

The traditional way to learn about the options and parameters of a un*x command is by using the `man` (manual) command, *e.g.*

```
man echo
```

If you issue that on your system, you should see a description of the `echo` command including something like

> Echo the STRING(s) to standard output.
>
> **-n**    do not output the trailing newline

Comment: `man echo` does not always work. I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.3 and when I try it, I get: `No manual entry for echo`